# Regular Expression Notepad increment numbers in every line

Tags: notepad++, auto-increment

I've to add numbers incrementally in the beginning of every line using Notepad++.
It is the not the very beginning. But, like

```
  when ID = '1' then data
  when ID = '2' then data
  when ID = '3' then data
  .
  .
  .
  .
  when ID = '700' then
```

Is there any way i can increment these numbers by replacing with any expression or is there any inbuilt-notepad functions to do so.

Thanks

Comment: it's not the job of a regex.

Comment: No, you can't do that with regex.

Comment: you can write a perl script for it.

Comment: is it. Just looking to reduce some pain in adding 700+ records. thank you anyway

Comment: use python.open a file in write mode.then a simple loop.

Comment: @rohin it needs a language. Which lang did you prefer?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I got a solution now. Check the answer. So, Please do avoid to say not possible in future and also bit of politeness will sound your capability further. I've read your deleted comment, which told me to delete my question after reading your first comment. It didn't bother me, because you are not the only one who knows the answer and in fact, i was awaiting a fitting answer to get back to you. Thanks anyway

Comment: @rohin yep, i told you to delete this question because of the answer you accepted before. And my point is correct, regex isn't does this job, it was done by an inbuilt function in the tool notepad++

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to do this with notepad++ you can do it in the following way.

First you can write all the 700 lines with template text (you can use a Macro or use the Edit -> Column Editor). Once you have written it, put the cursor on the place you want the number, click `Shift`+`Alt` and select all the lines:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @rohin yes, notepad++ it's amazing. Glad to help you.

Comment: @Fede +1 for finding the inbuilt notepad function.

Comment: @Fede What do I have to click/press in order to get that "Column / Multi-Selection Editor" dialog?

Comment: This is wonderful! I use notepad++ everyday and it doesn't stop surprising me. I bet I only scratch the surface of its capability.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to accomplish this with a regular expression, as you will need to have a counter and make arithmetic operations (such as incrementing by one).

Comment: You have marked this as answer?This didnt ans your question and also it was mentioned in comments before.

Comment: @vks It actually answers the question, and I don't seem to find (in the comments) an **actual explanation** of ***why*** a Regex can't be used

Comment: cannot agree to this.It has not helped him neither anybody else.An ans like something in another language like perl or python would have been better for being marked as answer.

Comment: @MatiCicero you could simply do this through awk. `awk '{print NR,$0}' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `cc.p` command of ConyEdit. It is a cross-editor plugin for the text editors, of course including Notepad++.

With ConyEdit running, copy the text and the command line below, then paste:

```
when ID = '#1' then data
cc.p 700
```

**Gif example**

[image: Gif Example]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I am putting this here in case it helps someone else in the future. There is a way to increment numbers in one pass with a regex search and replace in Notepad++ (I'm using v8.5.6). I haven't encountered any problems with these expressions so far in my own project.

In Notepad++ press ctrl-h, check the "Regular expression" box, and then in "Find what" paste this:

```
(?<!!!!!!)\b(?'m1'\d*?)(?'m2'(?'a'0)|(?'b'1)|(?'c'2)|(?'d'3)|(?'e'4)|(?'f'5)|(?'g'6)|(?'h'7)|(?'i'8)|(?'j'9))(?'m3'(?'pbn'9{128})?(?'p7'9{64})?(?'p6'9{32})?(?'p5'9{16})?(?'p4'9{8})?(?'p3'9{4})?(?'p2'99)?(?'p1'9)?(?<=9))?\b
```

and in "Replace with" paste this:

```
(?{pbn}!!!!!$+{m1}$+{m2}$+{m3}!!!!!:$+{m1}(?{a}1:(?{b}2:(?{c}3:(?{d}4:(?{e}5:(?{f}6:(?{g}7:(?{h}8:(?{i}9:(?{j}10))))))))))(?{p7}0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)(?{p6}00000000000000000000000000000000)(?{p5}0000000000000000)(?{p4}00000000)(?{p3}0000)(?{p2}00)(?{p1}0))
```

Do please note one limitation: this regex cannot carry a 1 more than 128 places. So if a number ends with more than 128 consecutive 9s, the regex will instead mark the unhandled number with '!!!!!' so that it can be found to do the addition manually.

```
!!!!!nnnnn..9 x 129+!!!!!
```

I *think* it will work for arbitrarily large numbers, as long as they don't have too many 9s at the end. But I didn't need this for numbers that big.

You can add more 2^x blocks of 9s to replace if you're working with really big numbers.  I haven't tried the expressions in other PCRE-compatible tools, but I imagine that if your regex engine supports named subexpressions, it'll work there too.

Comment: You could explain how it works. Moreover, it doesn't answer the question, they want to generate a list of numbers from 1 upto 700, your answer increment every number found in a text and doesn't work if there are no numbers in the text.