# Efficient increment number in a section of a mvc route using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a long url route and I only need to increment a section of the route.  Right code to increment this is very crude looking and seems buggy. I'm currently using regex in javascript, but maybe that too complicated:

/superbowl-XIX-**group01**-01/offense/11

I want to increment the group # route to this using javascript:

/superbowl-XIX-**group02**-01/offense/11

And I'm currently using this code:

```
        var nextRosterStr = "";
        nextRosterStr = $('#btnShowMore').attr("next-page");
        if (typeof nextRosterStr === 'undefined') {
            return;
        } else if (isUIButton === false) {
            // update the btnShowMore attribute as well
            var gNumberValue = nextRosterStr.match(/-group0?\d*-/g);
            gNumberValue = gNumberValue.toString().replace(/0/, "ZERO");
            var gNumberStr = gNumberValue.toString().match(/\d*/g);
            var gNumber = parseInt(gNumberStr.join(""), 10);
            gNumber++;
            var gNumberValueFinal = "";
            if (gNumber > 9) {
                gNumberValueFinal = gNumberValue.replace(/\d*/g, gNumber.toString(10));
                gNumberValueFinal = gNumberValueFinal.toString().replace("ZERO", "").toString();
            } else {
                gNumberValueFinal = gNumberValue.toString().replace(/\d+/g, gNumber.toString(10));
                gNumberValueFinal = gNumberValueFinal.toString().replace("ZERO", "0").toString();
            }

            var nextRosterStr = nextRosterStr.replace(/-group0?\d*-/g, gNumberValueFinal.toString());
```

btw here is a route setup example:

```
                new RouteMappingItem()
                    {
                        PageName   = "Superbowls",
                        Url        = "/{GameType}-{GameIdentifier}-group{groupNumber}-01/{formationName}/{rankingCount}",
                        Defaults   = new { controller = ...
                    },
```

There has got to be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can do it quickly with notepad++. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428620/regular-expression-notepad-increment-numbers-in-every-line/25429806#25429806

Comment: If you are defining the route, why not just specify each section as its own part of the route. IOW `/superbowl-XIX/2/1/offense/11`, where your route definition defines which part is what.

Comment: Needs to be done in javascript b/c I am constantly getting new URLs but the -group#- always stays the same.  This is dynamic changes not a one time thing.

Comment: Mike: I added a routing example.  But can't do this in razor... needs to be done in JavaScript.

Comment: I was thinking it would be easier to parse in JS if the URL only had a number in a particular place, not a bunch of extraneous information. If it was closer to what I showed, you could easily parse the URL just by parsing the text between the second and third slashes. Just a thought, which is why it's a comment :).

Comment: True dat dude.  I feel ya.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have different cases for less than 10 and greater or equal 10. Get the number, parse it, increment it, convert it to a string with leading zero, and put it back in the string.

Here is a trick to convert to string with leading zero:

```
numberAsString = ('00' + number).slice(-2);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/i9hOS9)

Comment: That is really great!  I'll up rank you when I get 15 pts.