# Using a regex to increment a number

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++

Using Notepad++ I want to replace :

All strings like `"pk": x` with `"pk": x+1` where x is a positive number.

`"pk": 42` would become `"pk": 43`.

Is there a regex that can suit my needs ?

Comment: [See this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428620/regular-expression-notepad-increment-numbers-in-every-line).

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace)

Comment: In [Funduc S&R tool](http://www.funduc.com/regexp.htm#Regular%20Expression%20Counters), you can use `"pk": +[0-9]` and replace with `"pk": %1>` if you have those values from 1. You can safely replace/increment the values in any regular programming language inside a callback replace function.