# Regex(?) Find & Replace with number increments in TextMate

Tags: regex, replace, textmate

I have the following:

```
<li id="xx"></li>
<li id="xx"></li>
<li id="xx"></li>
<li id="xx"></li>
```

and I'd like to use a quick find & replace to replace xx with xx01, xx02, etc. using TextMate Regular Expression search & replace.

i.e.

```
<li id="xx01"></li>
<li id="xx02"></li>
<li id="xx03"></li>
<li id="xx04"></li>
...
```

I'm struggling with this, I found how to do the other way around (ignore digit and replace all with the same), but not how to increment each replacement.

Ideas?

Comment: It is [possible with Npp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace), no idea if that is possible with TextMate.

Comment: I've answered a similar question but using Notepad++ in case you find it useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428620/regular-expression-notepad-increment-numbers-in-every-line/25429806#25429806

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, I didn't come here for this, but I'm glad I did. I use NPP and frequently need to do exactly that. TY

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible with TextMate Search & Replace, but there are some other TextMate options:

1. Select the text, then use Menu > Text > Filter Through Command and a perl, sed, or awk one-liner. For previous discussions of this problem in textmate and using tmcommand or macros, see:

   - http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/Incremental-Sequences-for-Replacement-td17059.html
   - http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/insert-a-column-of-numbers-td26917.html
2. Embed a custom command in a TextMate Bundle Editor > Menu Action. For a related command plugin (a python script) developed for Sublime Text 2 instead, see:

   - https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topics/1216-generate-a-sequence-of-numbers-increment-replace/